# CloudFormation create stack error "Error occurred while GetObject."

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-policies

I want to create a CloudFormation stack. It creates all the resources inside the template. But when it comes to lambda functions it fails with the error message:

**Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred while GetObject. S3 Error Code: NoSuchKey. S3 Error Message: The specified key does not exist. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: cdfeb740-263c-4b0a-9ef3-7adf63ccbfce)" (RequestToken: e57fb400-10d2-aaee-8a56-011125a20a53, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)**

Here's a piece from the template:

```yaml
ServerlessDeploymentBucket:
    Type: 'AWS::S3::Bucket'
    Properties:
      BucketEncryption:
        ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration:
          - ServerSideEncryptionByDefault:
              SSEAlgorithm: AES256
```

```yaml
AuthorizerLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
    Properties:
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref ServerlessDeploymentBucket
        S3Key: >-
          serverless/sensor-processor-v3/dev/1689595670583-2023-07-17T12:07:50.583Z/sensor-processor-v3.zip
      Handler: src/authorizer.handler
      Runtime: nodejs18.x
      FunctionName: sensor-processor-v3-dev-authorizer
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 30
      Environment:
        Variables:
          STAGE: dev
```

The message says that the error occurred while GetObject. Here's the only part where getobject mentioned

```yaml
IamRoleLambdaExecution:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Join 
            - '-'
            - - sensor-processor-v3
              - dev
              - lambda
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 'lambda:InvokeFunction'
                Resource: '*'
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - 's3:GetObject'
                  - 's3:ListBucket'
                  - 's3:PutObject'
```

I looked inside `serverless/sensor-processor-v3/dev/1689595670583-2023-07-17T12:07:50.583Z/sensor-processor-v3.zip` this file (Actually not this one, but prod version of this). The `zip` file contains the compiled javascript version of the code.

- **Should I create the bucket and deploy my code there manually?**
- **Cloudformation should create the bucket automatically. Am I right?**
- **The source code is deployed to GitLab. Where did the compiled jaavscript version of the come from?**